# Point on polygon edge

Tags: .net, graphics, 3d, geometry

What is the best way to determine if a point is on a polygon edge? We now use a distance between the point and its closest polygon edge but estimating a distance limit for all polygon cases is really a puzzle.

Any idea is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: "estimating a distance limit for all polygon cases is really a puzzle": can you tell more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle every edge separately and "enlarge" them to form of rectangular strip of a desired width.

This is done by projecting the test point onto the line of support of the edge, checking if the projection falls on the segment, and computing the distance between the two points.

Let `AB` be the edge segment and `P` the point. `Q(t) = A + t AB` is an arbitrary point along the edge and we want it to be the projection, so vectorially,

```
PQ(t).AB = (PA + t AB).AB = 0,

t = - PA.AB / AB²
```

It suffices to check that `t` falls in `[0,1]` and compute `|PQ(t)|`.

For nice handling at the corners, you can consider the distances from the point to the vertices.

Keep the shortest of all distances so computed.

[image]

Comment: I like your answer but our problem is to determine the fat line width.

Comment: @Alberto: What is the exact purpose of this tolerance in your application ?

Comment: We can have any polygon complexity and any polygon size. Currently we compute the fat line width using a fraction of the bounding rectangle diagonal but were wondering if a more "scientific" approach exists.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Why do you need this tolerance ?

Comment: I need the tolerance because due to rounding errors, points are not always "exactly" on the polygon.

Comment: Then your tolerance should probably be related to the accuracy of the coordinates themselves, depending on how they are obtained. But one level deeper, why does it matter that points are not "exactly" on the polygon ?